# Libpostal docker does not run on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am using libpostal for address parsing.Here is the git link: https://github.com/pasupulaphani/libpostal-docker

This docker image runs perfectly fine on my local machine but once I try and run it on EC2 it fails with below error.

```
Killed

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.138-114.102.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! node-zeromq@1.0.0 start: `DEBUG=libpostal:zeromq* node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-zeromq@1.0.0 start script 'DEBUG=libpostal:zeromq* node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-zeromq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     DEBUG=libpostal:zeromq* node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-zeromq
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-zeromq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-03T00_30_06_303Z-debug.log
```

I did reinstall the latest versions of `zerorpc`, `nodejs` and `npm` on the EC2 instance. But still cannot figure out the error.

Comment: Hi Ravi, what is your EC2 configuration? Which Dockerfile from the repository are you using?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2. It provides Linux kernel 4.14 tuned for optimal performance on Amazon EC2, systemd 219, GCC 7.3, Glibc 2.26, Binutils 2.29.1, and the latest software packages through extras.   docker pull pasupulaphani/libpostal-zeromq

Comment: How much RAM? Are you satisfying the pre-requisites?

Comment: I kept everything at the default settings... is it the RAM error ? I dont see anything related to out of memory though

Comment: The process might being killed because of it, take a look at it on /var/log/messages.

Comment: okay I will increase the resources and run it again and then update you.

Comment: When trying to install zerorpc I am getting the error  `no such file or directory, open '/home/ec2-user/package.json'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200374/discussion-between-ravi-and-roberto-goncalves).